# Loop for inserting a node into a binary search tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search tree. One method which I am trying to implement in the most efficient and stylish way is node insertion.
I am under the impression that  while (true) is a bad practice, correct?

```
    while (true){
        if(n <currentNode.data){
            if (currentNode.left == null){
                currentNode.left = new node(n);
                break;
            }else{
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            }
        }else 
            if (currentNode.right == null) {
                currentNode.right = new node(n);
                break;
            } else{
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            }
    }
```

and here is the whole code:

```
package graph;

public class BSearchTree {
    private node head = null;
    public BSearchTree(int [] entries){
        for (int a : entries){
            insert(a);
        }
    }
    public void insert(int n){
        if (head == null){
            head = new node(n);
            return;
        }
        node currentNode = head;
        while (true){
            if(n <currentNode.data){
                if (currentNode.left == null){
                    currentNode.left = new node(n);
                    break;
                }else{
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;
                }
            }else 
                if (currentNode.right == null) {
                    currentNode.right = new node(n);
                    break;
                } else{
                    currentNode = currentNode.right;
                }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BSearchTree bst = new BSearchTree(new int[]{2,4,1,5});  
        System.out.println(bst.toString());
    }


    private class node {
        int data = -1;
        node left = null;
        node right = null;

        public node(int n){
            data = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true)`just causes an infinite loop, is that what you want to do? If so, to me anyway, that's the simplest way to do it.

Comment: @no, I am processing a finite stream in a seemingly infinite  fashion, I dont want that.

Comment: I wouldn't say a `while (true) ... break` is necessarily bad practice. It can be nice then `do while`, and you don't always want to declare a boolean for no reason. Some consider `break` a form of goto (some also pre-function end returns gotos, but it's really just context-dependent), but sometimes it's clearer and more efficient than any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

(Just checking - you want your BST to be allowed to contain duplicates? That's what your current code does.)

Edit: After fixing some mistakes kindly pointed out by @vnp, here is an implementation of insert:

```
    public void insert(int n) {
        final boolean RIGHT = true;
        final boolean LEFT = false;

        node previousNode = null;
        boolean previousDirection = LEFT; // arbitrary
        node currentNode = head;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            previousNode = currentNode;
            if (n > currentNode.data) {
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
                previousDirection = RIGHT;
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
                previousDirection = LEFT;
            }
        }

        if (previousNode == null) {
            head = new node(n);
        } else if (previousDirection == LEFT) {
            previousNode.left = new node(n);
        } else {
            previousNode.right = new node(n);
        }
    }
```

This avoids using while(true) and break; and uses more shallow if statements, which I think makes it marginally easier to follow.

Comment: I don't see `node.next` defined anywhere. There are `node.left` and `node.right`.

Comment: @vnp Good point! I'm missing this. How about also storing a boolean previousDirection at each step, and using this to determine whether to go right or left? (That means declaring private final static boolean RIGHT = true; private final static boolean LEFT = false; at the start.)

Comment: Then I see no benefits (suggested implementation would be helpful). BTW, those `RIGHT` and `LEFT` do not belong to the class; they are local to `insert`.

Comment: @vnp thanks! I've provided an implementation - it's definitely arguable that this implementation is no better!

Comment: Is it also easier to understand? I mean compared to my solution?

Answer (score 1):

**`private class node`**

I suggest you declare it as

```
private static final class BinarySearchTreeNode<E> {

    E datum;
    BinarySearchTreeNode<E> left;
    BinarySearchTreeNode<E> right;

    BinarySearchTreeNode(E datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }
}
```

Above, `private` tells Java that the class is not accessible outside of enclosing `BSearchTree`, `static` removes an implicit reference to `BSearchTree` from each node object, `final` tells Java that it is not possible to inherit from `node`. Finally, I would go verbose here and rename `node` to `BinarySearchTreeNode`.

**Superfluous access modifier**

```
private class node {
    int data = -1;
    node left = null;
    node right = null;

    public node(int n){ // 'public' does not buy you here anything.
        data = n;
    }
}
```

**Adding generics**

Going for generic binary search tree is not much harder, so, as a further exercise, I suggest to add generics (see the **Summa summarum**.)

**Miscellaneous advice**

I suggest you rename `head` to `root`.

**Package name**

`graph` is too short and too uninformative name for you code's package. Consider renaming to, say, `net.villa.util`.

**Summa summarum**

Combining all the advices above, I came with this proposition:

```
package net.villa.util;

public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {

    private BinarySearchTreeNode<E> root;

    public void insert(E value){
        if (root == null) {
            root = new BinarySearchTreeNode<>(value);
            return;
        }

        BinarySearchTreeNode<E> node = root;
        BinarySearchTreeNode<E> parent = null;
        int cmp = 0;

        while (node != null) {
            cmp = value.compareTo(node.datum);

            if (cmp == 0) {
                // The 'value' is already in this tree.
                return;
            }

            parent = node;

            if (cmp > 0) {
                node = node.right;
            } else if (cmp < 0) {
                node = node.left;
            }
        }

        BinarySearchTreeNode<E> newNode = new BinarySearchTreeNode<>(value);

        if (cmp < 0) {
            parent.left = newNode;
        } else {
            parent.right = newNode;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("[");
        toStringImpl(stringBuilder, root, new Separator(""));
        stringBuilder.append("]");
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private static final class Separator {
        String separator;

        Separator(String separator) {
            this.separator = separator;
        }
    }

    private static <E> void toStringImpl(StringBuilder stringBuilder,
                                         BinarySearchTreeNode<E> node,
                                         Separator separator) {
        if (node.left != null) {
            toStringImpl(stringBuilder, node.left, separator);
        }

        stringBuilder.append(separator.separator);
        stringBuilder.append(node.datum);

        if (separator.separator.equals("")) {
            separator.separator = ", ";
        }

        if (node.right != null) {
            toStringImpl(stringBuilder, node.right, separator);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree<Integer> bst = new BinarySearchTree<>();
        bst.insert(3);
        bst.insert(1);
        bst.insert(0);
        bst.insert(2);
        bst.insert(5);
        bst.insert(4);
        bst.insert(7);  
        System.out.println(bst.toString());
    }

    private static final class BinarySearchTreeNode<E> {

        E datum;
        BinarySearchTreeNode<E> left;
        BinarySearchTreeNode<E> right;

        BinarySearchTreeNode(E datum) {
            this.datum = datum;
        }
    }
}
```